# Including multiple typescript files

Tags: javascript, php, typescript

I have a really simple question but I couldn't find any documentations for it.

I have 4 ts files.

```
/main.ts
/sub/forms.ts
/sub/validators.ts
/sub/location.ts
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code to code and when I save a TypeScript file, it auto compiles it and creates a JS file (ES5).

my problem is.. when I save main.ts file, how can I have forms.ts, validators.ts and location.ts in it as well?

In PHP, we simple use `include('filename.php');`

Is there way to do it in TypeScript?

main.ts;

```
import { Forms } from "./sub/forms";
import { Validators } from "./sub/validators";
import { Location } from "./sub/location";

let emp1 = new Validators('TEST');
emp1.greet();
```

/sub/validators.ts;

```
export class Validators {
    employeeName: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.employeeName = name;
    }
    greet() {
        console.log(`Good morning ${this.employeeName}`);
    }
}
```

main.js (after auto save compile)

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var validators_1 = require("./sub/validators");
var emp1 = new validators_1.Validators('TEST');
emp1.greet();
```

it doesn't import the validators.ts code into main.js

Comment: You use the import statement, like `import { Validator } from './sub/validator';` where `Validator` is an exported member( a class, interface or whatever).

Comment: @vivek_23 i updated the question, it has more info :)

Comment: It does import the validators: `var validators_1 = require("./sub/validators");`

Comment: @AlekseyL. do i have to compile main.js as well? if yes, how?